How to add `tailwindcss` to my Vue + Electron Forge project?
I'm doing my first sample project using Vue + Electron Forge with the template vite+typescript. Now I want to add tailwind but I can't seem to find any useful documentation online.
This is my project structure right now:

I tried the official docs but there is no information about it. I also tried in Google and even in this forum but the related questions where about webpack and vue-cli, which changes a lot than with vite.

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vue-3-vite

Thanks for the answer, It's the first time I try electron so I thought the steps were different
